# How do I set a breakpoint in a module other than the one I am running in Python IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

If I edit two modules, eggs and ham, and module eggs imports ham, how do I run module eggs such that IDLE stops at breakpoints set in ham? So far, I have only been able to get IDLE to recognize breakpoints set in the module actually being run, not those being imported.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. start IDLE
2. open eggs, open ham
3. set desired breakpoints in both files
4. go to IDLE's shell, select Debug=>Debugger
5. go back to eggs and  to run.

You should stop at break points in each file.  (It works, I just tested it.)

Comment: Yep, it works for me now too. A few hours ago, it didn't... I must not have been doing what I thought I was doing.

Comment: Re: Step 3. In Windows you right click. In OS X you middle click (requires 3 button mouse).

Comment: In Python 3, there's no menu called `Debugger`. You should specify that the user should go under `Run > Check Module` and then start the debugger... You should improve your answer, even though the OP was not asking directly for this, it is not so obvious what I mentioned...